# Spaceship exhaust light

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, node-editor, edit-mode, shaders

So I'm trying to have my X-Wing and Tie fighter exhausts light up like the ones below. 
[image]
Currently, they just look like this which isn't that nice. The material is just a red emission for the Tie fighter and a yellow emission for the X-Wing.

[image]
Anyone got any ideas on how to accomplish this effect, would it be something I would do later in After Effects. Also, how would I go about creating the laser beams like the ones in Image 1?, I was thinking of just using the saber plugin for After Effects but they never look that nice.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

3 things that you have to keep in mind:

1. You have to use the Filmic Color Management
2. The engine emission shader must be very bright and just a bit desaturated
3. You have to add a Glare node in "Node Editor" > "Compositing Nodes"

For the laser beam I've made this setup
[image]

The laser beam is just an elongated "drop" with a very bright green-yellow material. I've made the beam to move rapidly forward and i've enabled the motion blur option.