# Can anyone tell me how is this Rocket Engine flame animation was made?

Tags: animation, particles, smoke-simulation

I just saw the rocket engine flame animation in the youtube, and it mentions that animation was made by blender. please see the pic below.[image: Rocket Engine Flame]

And I start to wonder is this animation was made by particle?? or smoke?? or maybe it was made by mesh. The youtube link: [Rocket Engine Flame](https://youtu.be/otcUtKvzuoo)

If anyone knows, please tell me how to do it.

Thank you.

Comment: See https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-is-the-problem-with-posting-an-image-or-link-and-asking-how-do-i-do-this

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48816/how-to-create-a-fire-light-effect-in-a-spaceship-engine and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/105785/spaceship-exhaust-light and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53310/how-to-create-an-engine-glow-effect-for-spaceships-in-cycles?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Here is one example of rocket exhaust
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3ThjQkN4oQc